# Mongodb source code installation and makefile

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, makefile

I am dowloading the tarball file of mongodb and running it using config file which I created using the following command:
**./mongod --config /my_path_to/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu2004-5.0.6/mongo.conf --logpath /my_path_to/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu2004-5.0.6/logs/mongod.log **

Can someone help me that instead of this how can I use makefile and make command? What do we write in makefile?

Comment: What do you mean by makefile? There is no makefile in your question. MongoDB downloads are binary files, there is nothing to compile. In general I suggest to use either a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) **or** [command line arguments](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#options) but don't mix them as you do.

Comment: That is what my question was that can we use make? I didn't find any make file for MongoDB and used configuration to run it. 
I guess as you said MongoDB has all binary files so that maybe the reason that we don't  use make.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you insist to compile the source code by yourself, then you can download  the source code also from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community - but why generating trouble by yourself?

Comment: Thanks I did that. Actually it was part of my college presentation. They wanted me to demostrate the source code installation and also now wants a server where make command and have makefile is used :(

Comment: What is the reason to compile the source code by yourself? I would see it as a waste of time.

Comment: I don't know. The prof said that it is to test my linux skills lol..

Comment: I made a makefile with only run in it and run has the same command that I type on terminal to run mongod. It's crashing so will look into that

Comment: Still not clear what you need. If you like to install MongoDB then follow [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I did that. I also wrote a code in a makefile which basically runs ./mongod so my problem is hopefully solved. Thanks!